# Vagrant-libvirt install unsuccessful on Debian 11 Bullseye? "The provider 'libvirt' could not be found"

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, libvirt, vagrant

I am attempting to recover a dropped laptop hard drive and ended up installing Debian 11 fresh to a swapped SSD that I had cloned the internal SSD to but it still wouldn't work.

So I am recovering my files now (from Debian 10) and trying to install Vagrant as I had it set up with libvirt.

I've installed all the packages specified here: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-use-vagrant-with-libvirt-kvm-provider/ including virt-manager & the vagrant plugin vagrant-mutate.

I've added user to libvirt group as well and logged out & in (I think I tried rebooting too).

When I try running `vagrant status` in the directory where I have a Homestead install I was using (and also when I tried adding a new libvirt box) I get this message:

```
The provider 'libvirt' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'homestead'. Please use a provider that exists.

Vagrant knows about the following providers: hyperv, virtualbox, docker
```

`sudo systemctl status libvirtd` says active & running.

I know in my previous Debian 10 installation I was unable to get virtualbox to work right, and read that libvirt was likely faster & more stable, and once I got it working with Vagrant (which I remember was also a trying process but don't remember what I ultimately did to get it to work) I don't remember that it posed any problems.

Addendum: When I just try "vagrant up" on the new test box, it says

```
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

I don't really want to try installing virtualbox or any other though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved installing `libvirt-dev` package as well as executing `vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem. The reason was what I installed plugin as user `vagrant isnstall plugin vagrant-libvirt` thus plugin was installed in ~/vagrant.d. But I tried to up vagrant as root `sudo vagrant up --provider=libvirt`. In this case vagrant looking for plugins in /root/vagrant.d . Solution very simple: install plugin as root.